# Google Plus Signin Button error even on google official test page

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I thought my code was faulty but I can reproduce the same errors on the official google test page:

```
https://google-developers.appspot.com/+/demos/signin_demo_render
```

1. load the url above in your browser with javascript console open
2. click to insert the signin button
3. click the red G+ signin button
4. from the google login popup cancel the login

You get two beautiful javascript errors in

> cb=gapi.loaded_2 (row 8)

Depending on the browser you test, Chrome, Firefox or Safari, the error description is different, but always involve something being null.

My question is, anyone has solved it? Is there anyway to prevent the errors? I am scared as hell for some visitors could be a blocking error.

Comment: +1: and your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems google fixed it. Is not happening anymore.